# mean.js installation error on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack, meanjs

I tried to build the mean stack by following the installation steps in https://github.com/meanjs/mean

I cloned the code from git and run the command npm install

And got the below error towards the end.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\..\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Git_projects\meanjs\npm-debug.log

C:\Git_projects\meanjs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running a Windows system, and `node-gyp` on windows requires both *Python* and *Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013*. Depending on your setup you may also need to install the *Windows 7 64-bit SDK*.

See the [node-gyp docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) for more info.